# Single object binds but list collection does not

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Was attempting to bind a json collection to a list but failed. Unsure why. When doing a single object like so :

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public void Permissions_Set(Permission permissions_JSON)
{
    //foreach (var permission_from_view in permissions_JSON)
    //{
    //    //doStuff
    //}
}
```

**View**

```
<script>

    var data2 = { id: 1, user_id: 8, project_id: 1, mode: 3 };
    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/Permissions_Set",
        dataType: 'json',

        type: 'POST',
        data: data2,
        success: function () {
        }
    });
</script>
```

The object binds correctly. Yet when I use a list collection like so:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public void Permissions_Set(IList<Permission> permissions_JSON)
{
    //foreach (var permission_from_view in permissions_JSON)
    //{
    //    //doStuff
    //}
}
```

**View**

```
var data = { permissions_JSON: [{ id: 1, user_id: 8, project_id: 1, mode: 3 }, { id: 1, user_id: 8, project_id: 2, mode: 1 }, { id: 1, user_id: 8, project_id: 3, mode: 1 }] };
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Permissions_Set",
    dataType: 'json',

    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function () {
    }
});
```

it is able to figure out I have 3 objects in my collection but fails to bind the data to each object. As a result each object has an int of 0 (the default value of an int)

Here is the model

```
public class Permission
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public int project_id { get; set; }
    public int mode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the wrapper object around the array and send the array itself as data?

Comment: if I remove the wrapper the object returned to the controller is null.

Comment: why not using public void Permissions_Set(IEnumerable<Object> permissions_JSON), and then cast the objects to permissions or mapp them.

Comment: If that is an option I am unaware of how to make that work code wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the content type and adding the collection to an object did the trick

```
    var bob = {permissions_JSON:[{ id: 1, user_id: 8, project_id: 1, mode: 3}]};
request.permissions_JSON = bob;

$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Permissions_Set",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    data: JSON.stringify(bob),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set *traditional* parameter to true:

```
var data = { permissions_JSON: [{ id: 1, user_id: 8, project_id: 1, mode: 3 }, { id: 1, user_id: 8, project_id: 2, mode: 1 }, { id: 1, user_id: 8, project_id: 3, mode: 1 }] };
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Permissions_Set",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    traditional: true,
    success: function () {
    }
});
```

Comment: Using this code returns a permissions_JSON with no items to the controller